# Как написать специализацию метода шаблона класса?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

```
template <int N1>
class A
{  
public:
   template <int N2> int func();
};

template <int N1> template <int N2> int A<N1>::func()
{  return N1+N2;
}
    
//template <int N1> template <> int A<N1>::func<0>() //error
//{  return N1+1;
//}

int  main(void)
{  
   A<1> a;
   int x=a.func<2>();
   int y=a.func<0>();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вы же в курсе, что полная специализация вот так пишется? `template<> void func<int>() {}`. А не-полная для функций запрещена. `template<typename N1> template<> int A<N1>::func<int>() {}`

Comment: Да, но здесь в примере нет частичной специализации. Специализация есть, но она полная. Шаблон класса вообще без специализации. Шаблон функции внутри класса со специализацией, но с полной специализацией - все параметры шаблона функции в количестве одна штука определены полностью.

Answer (score 0):

В этом случае можно обойтись без специализации.

```
template <int N1>
class A
{  
   public: template <int N2> int
   func()
   {
       if constexpr (0 != N2)
       {
            return N1 + N2;
       }
       else
       {
            return N1 + 1;
       }
   }
};
```

Comment: Это мне не походит, хотя бы потому, что в качестве параметров шаблона могут быть типы, а с ними конструкции if(T==char) работать не будут. Более того в MSVC можно написать специализацию внутри класса, но это мне тоже не походит. Мне хочется знать правила языка c++, предусмотрена ли там такая конструкция, в которой описание функций класса разделено на декларацию внутри класса и реализацию вне класса, как сделано в примере.

Comment: @Vadim32 : `if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<T,char> )`

Comment: @Vadim32 Специализация функции разрешается только при специализации шаблона класса.

Answer (score 0):

Специализация метода требует специализации класса. А внутри класса написать такую специализацию вообще не получится. Дело в том, что такая специализация требует явного указания `scope`'а класса (например `A<int>::`), но так как мы уже находимся внутри класса, то писать его `scope` - тоже будет ошибкой. Такая вот весьма странная ситуация получается.

```cpp
#include <concepts>

template<typename CT> class A {
public:
    CT var;
    template<typename FT> int func() {
        if constexpr (std::same_as<FT,int>) {}
    }
};

template<> template<> int A<int>::func<int>() {}
```

Кстати, если используются `TTP` (а не `NTTP`), то возможно так будет лучше:

```cpp
template<typename CT> class A {  
public:
    template<typename FT> auto func(CT a1, FT a2) {
        return a1 + a2;
    }
};
```

Выведение типа возвращаемого значения из выражения `return`.